# Weak* convergence in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\Bbb R^m$ with smooth enough boundary so that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)=\text{Lip}(\Omega)$.

> Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence in  $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. What does it mean for the sequence to converge weak*-ly in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$?

I don't know what the pre-dual of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is. I know that for $p'=p/(p-1)$,
$$
W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)^* = W^{-k,p'}(\Omega) 
$$
but I don't know if it makes sense to talk about $W_0^{-1,1}(\Omega)$ or what it is, if it exists at all.

I would guess that $u_n\overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} u$ in $W^{1,\infty}$means that 
$$
\int_\Omega u_n f + \nabla u_n\cdot \mathbf g \ dx \to \int_\Omega u f + \nabla u\cdot \mathbf g \ dx
$$
for all $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ and all $\mathbf g\in L^1(\Omega;\Bbb R^m)$. Even if this is true I still want to know the name of this space and how we know that its dual is indeed $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: The preduals of Lip(X) are discussed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01812)

Comment: Your last paragraph is correct, interpreting the weak-star convergence with $f$ and $g$. See also [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14445/dual-of-sobolev-space-w1-pu-for-u-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbb-rn).